# What is scratch memory and how can I free some up without restarting?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I'm using Photoshop on Windows 7 X86 right now and am trying to save a project but I get an error "Cannot save file, not enough scratch memory."

What is scratch memory and is there a way to free it up without restarting (and losing my project)?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PS is not talking about RAM but disk here. It uses a scratch disk, which is propably full. You can configure this at Edit->Preferences->Performance

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I moved the slider all the way to the right, hit ok and I can now save my file.

Comment: [Check this article for more background info](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/photoshop/f/scratchdisk.htm)